# Can't access Node.childNodes getter on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am debugging a problem on an Android device. (using an emulator, but it is reproduced in many devices).
I am opening my page using the Android WebView browser

```
WebView in com.google.android.gms (39.0.0.0)
```

I am selecting the `body` element and reading it's `childNodes` property successfuly.
But I can't find the `childNodes` getter on the `Node.prototype`, and neither on its parents in the prototype chain.

```
const el = document.querySelector('body')
undefined
el instanceof Node
true
el instanceof HTMLBodyElement
true
el instanceof HTMLElement
true
el.childNodes.length
61
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype,'childNodes')
undefined
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLBodyElement.prototype,'childNodes')
undefined
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype,'childNodes')
undefined
```

The body element prototype chain:

```
HTMLBodyElement
HTMLElement
Element
Node 
EventTarget
Object 
null
```

`childNodes` doesn't exists as an `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` on none of those.

Is there a way for me to find how this `childNodes` property is added to the `Node.prototype` and to get this function?

Comment: Hi. Did you get any solution for this problem

Comment: Hey @Karthikkumar, I didn't manage to solve it, but found a certain workaround. I updated my answer and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to get the getter function in these specific old browsers (I guess it's a browser feature that blocks access to them).

I did a kind of a workaround instead:

```
 const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, functionName);
  if (descriptor?.get) {
    return descriptor.get;
  }
  if (descriptor?.value) {
    return descriptor.value;
  }
  // if no access - just a return a function that returns this property
  return function () {
    return this[functionName];
  };
```